# fgets reads lines **after** program executed with popen finishes

Tags: c, popen

Program *sdh*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void main(void) {
    FILE *fp = popen("/path/to/asd", "r");
    char str[256];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", str);
    }
}
```

Program *asd*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(void) {
    printf("A\n\r");
    sleep(1);
    printf("B\n\r");
}
```

When running program *sdh*, it waits for 1 second and then prints

```
A
B
```

What I would like it to do is print

```
A
```

, wait for 1 second, and then print

```
B
```

In other words, program *asd* finishes before `fgets` manages to read the first line. How should I modify this to be able to read the lines as soon as they are printed?

Comment: Your asd program should flush standard output after each write if you want that behavior.

Comment: (Also, main needs to return int. http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html)

Comment: (Also, just use `\n`, not `\n\r` for a line ending. The latter doesn't even match up with any OS I'm aware of, and stdio will translate `\n` to `\r\n` on Windows automatically when outputting text)

Comment: @Shawn, not right at all, some OS uses `\n\r`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: @KeineLust I wasn't aware of those. Still, I really doubt OP is using ACORN BBC or RISC OS in spooled text output mode...

Comment: @Shawn, yeah, I was nitpicking ;)

Comment: Thank you all for comments, flushing the stdout made the trick. And to he who downvoted my question: if you downvote, please tell why you did so. Asking this saved me couple of hours of googling, trying to find a solution to a problem which I didn't even know how to put into words.

Comment: @Shawn, good point about main returning int. I come from an embedded background where it's not really that big a deal since main usually shouldn't return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard output stream (stdout) is buffered by default which is flushed whenever the buffer is full. Having a newline in printf would flush immediately
only if the output is going to a console/terminal. But in your case, it's going to a pipe, so it won't be flushed.

Adding [`fflush(stdout);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) after each printf statement (in "asd" program) would give the desired behaviour i.e., flush the output immediately from stdio buffers.

But if you don't want stdio buffering then you can disable it altogether with [`setbuf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html). For example, add `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` at the beginning of "asd" program.

Alternatively, you could also use [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call which won't buffer at all, if you're on a unixy system.